# Device Cache Files don't exist warnings

Tags: ios, chromecast, google-cast

I am using Google Cast API 3.3.0.11401 for iOs and everything is working fine except that I am presented with warnings stating that some Device Cache Files don't exist (see below) on App launch.

How do I get rid of these, what do they mean?

```
+[NSMutableDictionary(GCKAdditions) gck_loadFromCacheWithName:] - Device cache file file://[PathToMySimulator]/data/Containers/Data/Application/[FolderOfMyApp]/Library/Caches/gck_nearby_devices.plist doesn't exist.
+[NSMutableDictionary(GCKAdditions) gck_loadFromCacheWithName:] - Device cache file file://[PathToMySimulator]/data/Containers/Data/Application/[FolderOfMyApp]/Library/Caches/gck_network_cache.plist doesn't exist.
+[NSMutableDictionary(GCKAdditions) gck_deleteCacheWithName:] - Device cache file file://[PathToMySimulator]/data/Containers/Data/Application/[FolderOfMyApp]/Library/Caches/gck_device_cache.plist doesn't exist.
+[NSMutableDictionary(GCKAdditions) gck_deleteCacheWithName:] - Device cache file file://[PathToMySimulator]/data/Containers/Data/Application/[FolderOfMyApp]/Library/Caches/gck_device_cache_v1.plist doesn't exist.
+[NSMutableDictionary(GCKAdditions) gck_deleteCacheWithName:] - Device cache file file://[PathToMySimulator]/data/Containers/Data/Application/[FolderOfMyApp]/Library/Caches/gck_device_cache_v2.plist doesn't exist.
+[NSMutableDictionary(GCKAdditions) gck_loadFromCacheWithName:] - Device cache file file://[PathToMySimulator]/data/Containers/Data/Application/[FolderOfMyApp]/Library/Caches/gck_device_cache_v3.plist doesn't exist.
```

(I saw questions containing the same error messages but they all referred to different problems which actually didn't correspond to the messages)